# Scrolling Text Assistance (HTML)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I currently have a loading screen for a garry's mod server found 
here - http://osng.co/Stuff/Gmod/Server.php?steamid=76561198032735356 
and I want to know how to add a scroll in text in the right content box as seen on http://moronyard.com/explorer/loading/

Please bare in mind I know just a little about html, js, and php. All help is accpeted.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, include your code and research in your question to show what hasn't worked for you. If not, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a scrolling text, you can simply use html `marquee` like this:

```css
marquee{height:100px;
}
```

```html
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="down" scrollamount="1">
  this text will scroll down....... this text will continuously scroll down... 
</marquee>
```

**Or you can use jquery `prepend` like this:**

```js
var i=0;

/**Run a timer that will append an items every 3seconds**/
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){
  i++;
  $('#container').prepend("<p>this is item number "+i+"</p>");
  
  if(i== 7)
    {
      $('#container').prepend("<p>successfully loaded 7 items</p>");
       stopMyTimer()
    }
      
    
}, 3000);

/**after you have loaded all your items, call this function to stop the timer**/
function stopMyTimer()
{
   clearInterval(myInterval);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
<div>
```

Comment: Thank you but not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: @JamesFritz what are you looking for?

Comment: @JamesFritz please check my updated answer

Comment: Worked great thank you.

Comment: @JamesFritz  I am glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

Scolling text up is even easier. The html looks like this. We need a wrapper with position relative and height equal to whatever you want. Then we need the child element which will be the element being moved. Then we need at least one element inside that to contain the text but can have more if you want. Also the line-height needs to be set to whatever the height is of the outerwrapper.

```
<div id="scrolltextup" style="border:1px ridge #004F72; overflow:hidden;
     position:relative; width:500px; height:20px;">
  <div id="textup" style="text-align:center; position:absolute; top:0;
      left:0; width:500px;">
    <div style="line-height:20px;">
      +++First Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      +++Second Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript to do it. We get height of the entire thing. This time we are change the "top" property. Since the distance to animate will always be the same we don't need to calculate duration and can just pass in the duration.

```
var scrollheight = $("#textup").height();

function scrolltextup(dur){
  $("#textup").animate({"top":"-=20"},{
    duration: dur,
    easing: "linear",
    complete:function(){
      $("#textup").children(":last").after("<div style='line-height:20px;'>"+
          $("#textup").children(":first").html()+"</div>");
      if($("#textup").children(":first").height() <=
           (parseInt($("#textup").css("top"))*-1)){
        $("#textup").children(":first").remove();
        $("#textup").css({"top":0});
      }
      setTimeout("scrolltextup(3000)", 500);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't fully understand how to implement this. Mind explaining a bit more? Sorry.